# Checking Proximity of two Locations in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an array of locations and when I add another I want to be able to check if the other locations in the array are within a block of the new one. This is the Code I have to find the current location:

```
//Geocoding Block
[self.geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation: locationManager.location completionHandler:
 ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

     //Get nearby address
     CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

     //String to hold address
    locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"]    componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
```

The array has yet to be created because I want to figure this out first, I dont know what should be held in the array (string...). I know how to do a search I just need to know how to compare the locations.

Comment: Where is the array of other locations that you're trying to compare to? I guess I'm not sure why you've shown us this geocoding method.

Comment: Look at the last sentence. I don't know what to put in the array because I don't know what part of the location needs to be compared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the distance between two locations using [the `distanceFromLocation:` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html) on CLLocation. (You can get a CLLocation out of a CLPlacemark with `myPlacemark.location`.) So if you have an array of CLLocation objects, and you want to find the ones that are within one block (1/20 mile, or about 80 meters), you can do this:

```
NSMutableArray *locationsWithinOneBlock = [NSMutableArray new];
for (CLLocation *location in myLocations) {
    if ([location distanceFromLocation:targetLocation] <= 80.0)
        [locationsWithinOneBlock addObject:location];
}
```

This assumes you have an array `myLocations` of CLLocation objects that you want to filter against a single CLLocation called `targetLocation`.